# rsyslog using short hostname

Tags: linux, hostname, rsyslog

I'm using CentOS 6.5 and `rsyslogd`:

```
Name        : rsyslog
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.8.10
Release     : 8.el6
```

In rsyslog.d's conf file I have:

```
$PreserveFQDN on
```

and

```
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
```

No matter what I do, apps like `ntpd` still log with the short hostname and not the fdqn. Even 'logger -t test this' still shows the short name.

```
   [root@web-01 ~]# hostname -s
   web-01
   [root@web-01 ~]# hostname -f
   web-01.productA.internal
```

Even explicitly setting the hostname in rsyslog doesn't seem to work.

Using the `RSYSLOG_DebugFormat` template

*Logger*

```
    [root@web-01 ~]# logger -t test 456
    [root@web-01 ~]# tail /var/log/messages
    Debug line with all properties:
    FROMHOST: 'web-01', fromhost-ip: '127.0.0.1', HOSTNAME: 'web-01', 
    PRI: 13, syslogtag 'test:', programname: 'test', APP-NAME: 'test', 
    PROCID: '', MSGID: '-', TIMESTAMP: 'Feb 20 21:50:12', 
    STRUCTURED-DATA: '-', msg: ' 456' escaped msg: ' 456'
    inputname: imuxsock rawmsg: '<13>Feb 20 21:50:12 test: 456'
```

*Restart rsyslog*

```
    Debug line with all properties:
    FROMHOST: 'web-01', fromhost-ip: '127.0.0.1', HOSTNAME:
    'web-01.productA.internal', PRI: 43,
    syslogtag 'rsyslogd-2026:', programname: 'rsyslogd-2026', APP-NAME: 
    'rsyslogd-2026', PROCID: '', MSGID: '-',
    TIMESTAMP: 'Feb 20 21:53:19', STRUCTURED-DATA: '-',
```

Why would those be different?

Comment: FWIW, I see this behavior when I'm using the RSYSLOG_ForwardFormat template.  There are a handful of messages that always use the short name.  I haven't isolated the problem yet, but I'm guessing that it's a bug in rsyslog v5.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation about templates in rsyslog, titled: [Templates](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_templates.html).

The difference you're encountering is directly driven by the selection of `RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format` vs. `RSYSLOG_DebugFormat` formats.

It's not clear to me what the actual definition is for the `RSYSLOG_DebugFormat` template but [according to this thread](http://www.rsyslog.com/using-a-different-log-format-for-all-files/) it doesn't appear to be defined anywhere in an official way.

[image: ss of thread]

Suffice to say that the "Debug" template obviously includes the FQDN version of the hostname whereas the "Protocol123Format" does not.

Comment: the above example, both are using the debug format and  the HOSTNAME is different for both. This is where I'm stuck at. I cant figure out why one line has the fqdn and the other does not.

Comment: @ErikMathis - can you make this more clear in your Q? It's not obvious what you did to generate those logs.